# How to get path from image ID?

Tags: android, cursor

I extract image id from cursor to ArrayList

```
cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
```

I pass this ID to another activity and then i need to get the path of this Image for File() from it ID.

How can i do it?

i need something like this:

```
Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
            context.getContentResolver(), BitmapId,
            kind, bmOptions);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
      Cursor cursor = null;
      try { 
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
      } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
          cursor.close();
        }
      }
    }}
```

Okay here is a module for getting a file path from URI. if you get Image URI then just pass it to this funtion it'll return real path.Except of passing ID to another activity pass URI and get URI from that activity.

Comment: if so, i can get PATH with ID but i get the list of ALL IMAGE ID on device and pass to another activivty only 2 of them. i dont need any extra data. i just want to get path by id! is is possible? if not i know what to do.

Comment: Alright how abou this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997873/how-to-view-image-through-image-id-in-android

you can get the URI from imageID and then use the above fuction to get real path.